# Download file from internet (HTTPS) using Inno Setup version 5 (5.3.11) only

Tags: inno-setup, setup-project, inno-download-plugin, inno-tools-downloader, dwinshs

I cannot use Inno Setup 6 or above (which has built-in download support) as many of my users are still using Windows 7 (without any updates like SP1) and setup created with version 6 is failing there (even after Setting `MinVersion` to 6.0).

What I have already tried:

1. **Inno Download Plugin** by Mitrich Software – I am using Inno Setup
   5.3.11 and it gives below error on first line (`#include <idp.iss>`):

> To be able to use compiler directives other than '#include', you need
> Inno Setup Preprocessor (ISPP) which is currently not installed.
>
> To download and install ISPP, get the Inno Setup QuickStart Pack from
> http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php#qsp.

I tried searching **Inno Setup QuickStart Pack** on given URL, but could not locate as it is removed.

2. **InnoTools Downloader** – This does not support HTTPS which is required.
3. **DwinsHs** (Downloader for Inno Setup) – This has some odd requirement of adding link on my website which doesn't suite my need. Also, I tried it but giving same error as #1.

Any help to get https download working in Inno Setup 5.3.11 version is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Inno Setup version history, the latest version (currently 6.2) should support vanilla Windows 7 with `MinVersion=6.0`. I suggest you recheck this option to avoid using old versions.

---

Anyway, you can download any older version of Inno Setup from:
https://files.jrsoftware.org/is/

The preprocessor is included in Inno Setup installers for quite some time. It's definitely included in latest IS5, the 5.6.1.

---

You can probably also do without preprocessor altogether. Just copy and paste the contents of the `idp.iss` in place of the `#include <idp.iss>`. You will also have to manually preprocess the directives in the `idp.iss` itself. But there are only handful of them.

Comment: Thanks for idea of using older version having preprocessor. Just for the sake of completeness and for future developers coming here for solution, I downloaded 5.6.1 version from https://files.jrsoftware.org/is/5/. I also had to make some adjustments shown at https://groups.google.com/g/inno-download-plugin/c/yjAJkjynBTE.